# React native offline maps using OpenStreetMap

Tags: react-native, leaflet, react-native-maps

React Native - rookie question how to built an app with offline maps based on OpenStreetMap tiles?
Business needs are: user download the app after that download the tiles from remote server. 
Where to store the tiles? Which way would be the best optimal solution:

1. Using expo + react-native-maps download tiles from remote server and after that save locally in device and display it as LocalTile?
2. Using Leaflet with React Native WebView get tiles from remote server save it locally in IndexedDB

Any other, better idea?

Comment: Have you tried https://www.npmjs.com/package/cached-react-native-maps and https://pusher.com/tutorials/offline-react-native-part-1

Comment: Thank you Radulle that's nice one. But I have a very 'special' business needs. Posibble Scenario: user downloading the app in Amsterdam then he is  using it with fully map support in the island at the end of the world where the Wifi is completly dead. Your solution with react-native-offline suggest that I need to download the tiles in the background at the start based on specyfic latitude and longitude and all area around them, then store it in react-native-offline?

Comment: I'm also curious about advantages and disadventages of using native solutions over hybrid like Leaflet becouse I need a solid solution excluding non-functional.

Does react-native-maps can working without Google Maps, only with OpenStreetMaps in Android and iOS? I saw a strange Google Maps behind my OpenStreetMap tiles in the background even when I was using this library with OpenStreetMap as provider.

Comment: Yes, same as with Google Maps, you would have to predefine countries/cities so that user wouldn't have to define them manually. I do not know if it works with React Native, but Here Maps application has this feature where you select country and all the maps are downloaded. I also do not know if they have it implemented in API, you'd have to check. For the second question I am not sure to be honest, I see there are some use cases, but this offline requirement can be a bit tricky.